# MVC Scaffolding not showing fields on view in EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently trying to learn .NET core 2.0 and ASP.NET and doing a code-first approach on a project.

The problem is that the view (/Packages/) is not showing the categories, even though they are marked as [Required] at the class, the Scaffolding is somehow ignoring it and just creating the view without it.

This is a big problem because if you try to edit or add a new entry, it will just hang in there as Category is a required field in the DB. Needless to say, it is also not showing the list of Products as well... What am I missing?

**Package.CS**

```
public class Package
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Required] public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

**Category.CS**

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.CS**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SKU_ID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }

    public List<Variation> Variations { get; set; }
}
```

**DatabaseContext.CS**

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Combo> Combos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Package> Packages{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Variation> Variations { get; set; } 
}
```

I've even tried with and without

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    #region Package -> Product Relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Package>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Products);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Package>()
       .HasOne(xa => xa.Category);
    #endregion
}
```

This is how the View Looks:

[View At Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9I5o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, to answer my own question and in hopes that if somebody new like me encounters the same issue, knows how to fix it.

Turns out that I was not properly implementing the relationship on my model, so Entity Framework was unsure if it was really a relationship or what exactly it was...

So in short, you must let all the classes that interact together know that their field will be used and by whom.

**Package.CS**

```
public class Package
    {
        public int PackageId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }
```

Please, note that you also have to let the model you intend to use your other class know what field is the key. In my case:

> public int CategoryID { get; set; }

**Category.CS**

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }
    }
```

And pretty much those are all the changes I had to do on my model.

> If, for any reason, you just get the ID of your table to show on the
>   SelectView, don't panic. Just means you forgot to mark as [Required]
>   the text field. [you cannot allow nulls]